# CSS file is not loading in django project

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, python-2.7

I have added the static file link for all the css files. Still only the HTML file displays in the browser. The CSS file is not working. Please tell me if anything is wrong or not. How to correct it?

I went to the page source for my *index.html* page and clicked the CSS link. It does not show the CSS file. it shows some other HTML file. I get the error: `error page not found`.

**index.html**

```
<head>{% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %} /static/style1.css" type="text/css" />
  <title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/loginpage/" name="myForm" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Login</legend>
      <br>
      <p style="display:inline">Username</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="user" autocomplete="off" placeholder="username" size="30" autofocus required/>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p style="display:inline">Password</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="password" name="pass" autocomplete="off" placeholder="password" size="30" required/>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" style="height:30px; width:70px" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <p style="font-family:arial; color:#FFFFFF;">{{message}}</p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="/formlink/" id="sign">Create account</a>
</body>
```

**style1.css**

```
legend {
    border: medium none;
    left: 39%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font: normal 130% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
}

body  {
    background-image: url("12.jpg");
}

fieldset {
    position: absolute;
    left: 600px;
    top: 280px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

form {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font: normal 100% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#home {
    background-color: grey;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: normal 100% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
    left: 1450px;
    top: 100px;
}

#home:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#sign {
    background-color: grey;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: normal 100% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    left: 680px;
    top: 650px;
}

#sign:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've gone to great lengths to try and get the static prefix and then you add on what I assume is the static directory anyway, you can just use the [`static`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) tag

```
{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %} /static/style1.css
```

should be

```
{% static 'style1.css' %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplicity:)

Comment: It is just the spelling mistake in settings.py file I put STATICFILES_DIR instead of STATICFILES_DIRS. This the mistake. Anyways thank you.